# Using Octave, construct an algorithm that cuts off pauses for a speech signal

Tags: signal-processing, octave, convolution

Can you please explain how to do this? (Using Octave, construct an algorithm that cuts off pauses for a speech signal)

The audio file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/34ait9wo4b1j1ld/test1.ogg?dl=1

Here is my plan:

1. Read the audio file
2. Create a filter core to filter out high-frequency noise, "peaks" in the signal, especially during breaks
3. Apply this filter using convolution
4. Set a threshold for the filtered audio signal: pauses to 0, the rest to 1.
5. By combining the original and filtered signals, construct a new signal without pauses.

The issue is that I don't know how to start / do it in Octave. I only know a bit of theory.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use Octave? How about [truncate silence](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/truncate_silence.html) in Audacity?

Comment: Yeah, the task is to use Octave

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, to get you started.

For step 1, basic Octave's audio processing features are described in the [manual](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Audio-Processing.html).

To check your file use the `audioinfo` command (this example assumes `.ogg` file is in Octave's current working directoy):

```
info = audioinfo ('test1.ogg')
```

which should give you an struct with the audio metadata (compression method, number of channels, sample rate, etc.).

To read the file use the [`audioread`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Audio-File-Utilities.html) command:

```
[y, fs] = audioread ('test1.ogg');
```

where `y` is a column vector if you have a single channel (or each channel in a column if more channels), and `fs` is the sampling frequency.

To play the audio use:

```
player = audioplayer (y, fs); 
play (player);
```

For steps 2 and 3 you'll need to get the [signal processing](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/index.html) package, see how to install packages [here](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html).

I understand you want a low-pass filter like a [FIR filter](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/fir1.html), or a [Butterworth filter](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/butter.html). Both do low-pass as default.

For example, for a `n`-order Butterworth filter with cutoff `pi*Wc`, create and aplly filter:

```
[b, a] = butter (n, wc);
yf = filter (b, a, y);
```

Whereas for a `n`-order FIR filter with cutoff `pi*Wc`:

```
b = fir1 (n, Wc);
yf = filter (b, 1, y);
```

I guess that for FIR filters both [`filter`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/filter.html) and [`conv`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Products-of-Polynomials.html) work similarily, but for using `conv` you need to take the input's polynomial coefficients (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/610176-how-to-use-the-convolution-function-rather-than-filter-for-signal)).

There are many creepy details around, which strongly depend on your goals, and what your data is. Things can be as complicated as described [here](https://forum.smartcitizen.me/t/about-filters-and-convolution-signal-processing-for-audio-part-iv/945/1), see [this code](https://github.com/oscgonfer/AudioI2S/tree/dev_i2s_dbg/OCTAVE).